# How to remove my mobile icon in MSN?

Tags: windows-live-messenger

When I'm offline, the icon of mobile appear to other people at MSN.

How can I remove this icon, to people don't see it anymore?

I already saw the option "allow friends to send messages to my mobily phone", but this item is already unchecked and disabled to manage.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Answer (score 1):

All solutions I found use a very old version of MSN Messenger which is no longer available. You may need to upgrade.